# If the current entering a charge preamplifier is a positive pulse, could the output voltage really be a positive pulse?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electrical-engineering

In this web page:
http://physicsopenlab.org/2017/09/27/charge-sensitive-preamplifier/

they show the input voltage to a preamplifier and the output voltage.
[image]

If I do the quick computation (see below), I deduce that the web page made an error in the sign of the output voltage: it should be a voltage that goes more and more negative, and not as they show: more and more positive.

Am I right or is the web page right?

Now, a related question: if electrons would be created in the detector by an ionizing particle, will the current "id" be a positive pulse or a negative pulse ? I would believe that actually, id should be a negative pulse. In this case, we would obtain the positive output voltage.

Any comment?

Here is my computation:

[image]

Comment: Kind of up to the particular preamp. Check the specs.

Comment: I thought that preamp was a simple integrator with an operational amplificator, thus giving the minus sign ?

Comment: Classic Ortec preamps had the output with the same sign as the input. While a simple model might give a different result, you need to look inside at the actual design. Having an inverting buffer has some advantages.

Comment: Thank you so much. You may copy your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The first graph on the web page you referenced should be a negative pulse.  Further down the referenced page is the actual circuit with the reversed biased SiPM connected to the negative input of an opamp with a capacitor in the feedback.  An ionizing particle causes electrons to flow out of the "n" end of the SiPM which are integrated by the classic inverting opamp integrator … producing a positive output voltage that slowly decays.  Further down the referenced page are scope traces showing the correct polarity pulses.  This is all how you correctly understood it.